# How to use go receiver when struct is defined in imported package

Tags: linux, go, network-programming, netlink

currently working with the `vishvananda/netns` package trying to extract routes from a specific network namespace.

There is a defined `Handle` struct which is returned when I request a 'handle' for a specific network namespace. As such:

`func NewHandleAt(ns netns.NsHandle, nlFamilies ...int) (*Handle, error)`

This is then a receiver argument (?) to a function that requires that handle,

`func (h *Handle) LinkList() ([]Link, error)`

I'm new to go and not sure how to tie these together. I'm stuck with:

```
func (h *Handle) showInts() {
  int, err := h.netlink.LinkList()
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }

  for i, r := range int {
      log.Printf("%d: %s", i, r.Attrs().Name)
  }
}


func main() {
    ints, err := netlink.LinkList()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i, r := range ints {
        log.Printf("%d: %s", i, r.Attrs().Name)
    }

    pid, err := netns.GetFromPid(9097)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    netlink.NewHandleAt(pid)
    showInts()
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update

While writing the original answer, touched on a number of things, without any clear structure, so here's a more structured version:

Depending on what you're actually asking (ie *"How do I add a receiver function/method to an exported type"*, or *"What the hell is a receiver function"*), the answers are as follows:

#### How do I add a receiver function to an exported type?

Easy, same as you do with any other type. You were close, in fact. This doesn't work:

```
func (h *Handler) showInts() {}
```

Because you're adding a method to the `Handler` type in *your* package. Given you have a `main` function, that would be the `main` package. You're trying to add it to the `netlink.Handler` type instead. In which case, this will work:

```
func (h *netlink.Handler) showInts(){}
```

The type is `netlink.Handler` in your main package after all... This, however will *not* work. The compiler will refuse to compile, telling you: *"Cannot define new methods on non-local type"*. This is easily mitigated, though, by creating a new type, and add the method there:

```
type MyHandler netlink.Handler
func (h *MyHandler) showInts(){}
```

Be that as it may, the last 2 lines in your code strike me as wrong.
Given that `NewHandleAt` returns `(*Handle, error)`, and `netlink.Handle` is a receiver argument, the correct way would be:

```
var mh *MyHandle
if h, err := netlink.NewHandleAt(pid); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err) // something went wrong
} else {
    mh = (*MyHandle)(h)
}
mh.showInts() // call showInts on mh, which is of type *MyHandle
```

The fact that you've *"wrapped"* the external type in a custom type does mean you'll find yourself casting the same thing quite a lot. Say `netlink.Handle` has a `Test` method, and you want to call it inside `showInts`:

```
func (h *MyHandle) showInts() {
    nh := (*netlink.Handle)(h) //cast required
    nh.Test()
}
```

I'd also change the varname from `pid` to `nsh` or something, because it's a `NsHandle`, and not a `pid` after all...

---

#### What is a receiver argument?

Because you wrote this:

> This is then a receiver argument (?) to a function that requires that handle,

I get the impression you're not entirely clear on what a receiver argument is. Put simply, it's like a function argument, but instead of an argument that is just passed to a function, it's an argument that holds the object/value on which the function is called. Basically, it's the *"instance"* on which the function/method is called. Think of it as the `this` keyword in many OOP languages:

```
func (h *MyHandle) showInts() {
    return
}
```

In something like C++ would be

```
class MyHandle : Handle
{
    public:
        void showInts(void) { return; } // replace h with this
}
```

There are significant differences, however:

- The receiver argument can be a pointer, or a value - in case of a value receiver, the method cannot modify the receiver value
- There's no such thing as private, public, or protected... at least not in the traditional OO way
- ...

There's quite a few differences, perhaps consider going through the golang tour. The stuff about go methods can be found [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1)

---

#### Other issues/weird things

After looking at your code again, I'm really not sure whether this is correct:

```
h.netlink.LinkList()
```

In your `main` function, you call `netlink.LinkList()`. `h` is a `*netlink.Handler`. If you need to call the `netlink.LinkList` function, it's highly likely `h.netlink.LinkList` is **not** what you want to do. Instead, you should simply call `netlink.LinkList()`.
That's assuming you need to call the function in the first place.

Given that you've already called it in the `main` function, why not pass it as an argument?

```
//in main:
ints, err := netlink.LinkList()
//...
h.showInts(ints)

func (h *MyHandle)showInts(ll []netlink.Link) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Elias, awesome answer!

From that, I've written the following code which will list interfaces belonging to a specific namespace. Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/vishvananda/netns"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"
    "log"
)

type NSHandle netlink.Handle

func (h *NSHandle) showInts() {
  nh := (*netlink.Handle)(h) //cast required
  int, err := nh.LinkList()
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }

  log.Printf("Namespace Ints:")
  for i, r := range int {
      log.Printf("%d: %s", i, r.Attrs().Name)
  }
}

func getNSFromPID(pid int) (*NSHandle) {
  hpid, err := netns.GetFromPid(9115)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  var nsh *NSHandle
  if h, err := netlink.NewHandleAt(hpid); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err) // something went wrong
  } else {
      nsh = (*NSHandle)(h)
  }
  return nsh
}

func main() {
  getNSFromPID(9115).showInts()
}
```